# W3 Total Cache, CDN and Custom Post Types

Tags: cdn

I have W3 Total Cache installed so that I can serve images from my live website to a local development version. Everything seems to be working as expected, apart from the URL rewrite doesn't seem to happen on a custom post types pages.

I don't have the caching switched on, and the CDN hostname replacement is working very well on every other page.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to get http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-regex-replace/ and simply replace the full absolutely path to the wp-content/uploads folder.

Comment: Another option is to export your MySQL database to a .sql file and download it locally, then do a search & replace for the live site's URL to replace it with the dev site URL. Then drop the tables in the database and import the .sql file back in.